# Snarky comments to an elementary math question

Tags: discussion, comment

I have an issue to some to the comments of this following question that I had answered:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168288/how-much-more-money-is-needed-to-get-to-1-2-million-if-you-have-one-million-fi/1168289#1168289

I am providing images to follow, for the under 10k rep users in case the question itself becomes deleted.

I had simply given a hint to the OP, as below:

[image]

Granted, the OP's question (see below image) is a basic subtraction problem. I'm all for helping out as much as I can, even with questions as elementary as this one. However, I am disturbed by the responses that follow my answer (see above image; e.g. "Please post only serious answers"), as well as some responses that follow the question as well.

[image]

Unsurprisingly, the OP did not take this well. After all, I too found that some of these comments were mean-spirited in nature.

My question is: Is there any way that the more experienced users can be more welcoming and supportive of new users, in general? (I say "in general" because this question wouldn't count: The OP states that she is 10 years old, which is below the minimum age of 13 years to use this site.)

Furthermore, is it "wrong" to answer elementary level questions? I gave a **hint** (*not* an answer, as some users will unfortunately debate), and accordingly I received some backlash as well in the comments to follow my answer.

Needless to say, I am a little angry at this moment, as of writing up this post. So I apologize if my tone here is off-putting.

Comment: I think it comes across as the OP trolling - especially with her follow-up comments. I can't see a 10 year old going on MSE (or knowing about it!) for a subtraction problem over speaking to teachers/parents. In that case, I think that's where a lot of humour comes from - probably guessing the post will be deleted. 

I can't see what's wrong with your answer. There's not much more you can say without explicitly giving the answer.

Comment: Fellow math majors I knew in college didn't even know about MSE...highly doubt a 10 year old would. I agree with @MikeMiller

Comment: I am not sure if there is any way at all that we can help her (rude) self to subtract two numbers. This question was bad in multiple ways. The best course of action is to not answer questions like these and leave some tips for asking questions on MSE.

Comment: @dragon I wish that you would stop throwing around derogatory adjectives about other users who simply reacted appropriately to a trollish question.

Comment: @Did My post describes only comments left by other users, not the users themselves.

Comment: I agree that the reactions where not overly constructive. But I also think your answer is not good. Even if you do not want to do all the work you could have at least explained why one needs to subtract, that is spell out the equivalence of $a+x = b$ and $x = b-a$. Or offer some other explanation. The combination of a low-effort answer to a basic question  is what I find slightly problematic here (and other places).

Comment: @dragon Are you yourself convinced by the distinction in your comment? Sorry but I am not and I see it as, mainly, a wordplay.

Comment: @Did Yes, I am convinced with what I stated in my comment.

Comment: @crash: Are you saying that a 10-year old is not capable of googling for "[ask a math question](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=ask+a+math+question)"? (top result for me is MSE's "ask a question" page...)

Comment: A bit late to the party here, but the MSE description reads "For people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields". Are we here to help people/receive help with mathematics or are we here to whip each other in the face with our math dicks? If someone asks a question related to mathematics, it's their first question on the site, and they don't ask their question in the desired format straight off the bat, help and educate them. If they are trolling, good luck to them. It in no way affects you negatively if you help someone, whether their question is sincere or otherwise.

Comment: The point that, assuming the asker was sincere, her parents would be a better source than us deserves merit. Put more broadly, should we attempt to be a resource that we are not? In the case of education I think that less-than-ideal resources can in fact hinder the learner. However, I am interested in others' thoughts, especially @Eliot's who I am partly responding to.

Comment: @Karl: I see no reason to assume that her parents are (or for that matter are not) a better source than we are. Nor do I see how answering her question is attempting to be a resource that we are not.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott They know her and have a better idea of what she knows, they have access to her materials including any information on strategies she learned in class, and of course it should be assumed they understand how to resolve that problem based on its ubiquitous nature in both their education and the "real" world. Your second sentence is a misrepresentation of my view.

Comment: @Karl: They know her, yes; however, they may or may not have any real idea of what she knows, and they may or may not have the time, energy, or willingness to help. Not all families work as one might like. I’m certainly not going refuse my help on the assumption that she has other, better sources of help just because in an ideal world she ought to have them. \\ If my second sentence misrepresents your view, you didn’t state that view very clearly: what you wrote clearly implies that answering her question is a specific instance of attempting to be a resource that we are not.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Regarding the second sentence, I somehow misread it, and I apologize for that. It is evident that we have lost track because of your honest concern that you do not see what I am getting at. The real question I am raising is unrelated to this meta thread and it is based on the assumption that in some scenario there is a better resource available to the asker: should we still provide an answer? I don't care that it is purely hypothetical because we will never know for sure the circumstances of the asker; but in such cases would it not be more harmful for them to rely on our input?

Comment: @Karl: I’m sure that there are cases in which relying on our input is less than optimal, but I really think that getting our input is very unlikely to be actively harmful. And the very nature of Stack Exchange should be sufficient warning that there are no guarantees. In general my bias is strongly in favor of trying to help and opposed to turning people away because of some small chance that our help might prove misguided.

Comment: On the narrow question of who is a better source of help: a child's parents generally aren't in the classroom and don't know how the subject was taught--even parents who are strong in math (and not all are!) occasionally find their children's homework obscure. The teacher for that matter may have a blind spot to the child's real question; many smart people misunderstand questions sometimes, and why should teachers be immune from this? There is no one person who must _necessarily_ be best able to answer such a question.

Comment: @psmears Why would someone google "ask a math question"? That seems absurd. Any moderately intelligent person would either google his/her specific question or something along the lines of "free math help" or "free math tutoring"; MSE does not show up in the top 5 results for either query.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld I think it's up to the end-user to decide whether or not this place is helpful or harmful to their learning. In my case it has been helpful, as I've not run into any math wankers yet. I was a bit shocked when I saw this thread. I don't think members of MSE need to attempt to be anything except welcoming and helpful whenever anyone asks a math question. This isn't a university or a classroom, true! But it is still a place of learning. If one takes the time to answer on this site, they should keep in mind that it's a person on the other end who has taken the time to ask for help.

Comment: @crash: People's minds work in different ways. It might seem absurd to you, but plenty of people just type whatever's on their mind into Google - eg "Where can I ask a math question?" - and see where it goes. I also think you are underestimating the ability of 10-year olds to find things on the internet - MSE is hardly a secret!

Comment: @psmears I am not underestimating anyone's ability to navigate the Internet effectively. Simply think of how MSE works. Most of the people that use MSE consistently know $\rm\LaTeX$--what 10-year old knows how to use $\rm\LaTeX$? Not many. Also, almost all of the questions on MSE are aimed at lower to upper undergraduate math. A 10-year old, unless he or she be moderately Terrence Taoish, would find this site more annoying than helpful.

Comment: @crash: Most people on MSE? Sure! *Everyone* on SE? That would be quite a claim. And none of this is indicated by the "ask a question" page, so a newcomer wouldn't necessarily be put off.

Comment: Doesn't matter anyway, if OP is under 13, all content must be nuked by law.

Comment: @bjb568 It's not that simple: users under 13 can participate if they do not provide any private information to SE (as Doorknob did).

Comment: @Woodface Name counts as PII. (Diane Smith from the username)

Comment: @psmears Note that you are commenting on a thread in math meta and not general SE meta. That's a big difference and my previous comments apply. I never made an absolute claim about 10-year olds. I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: @bjb568 If my name was private information, I would have a great deal of trouble communicating in any community. I'm quite sure that users (underage or otherwise) are not *required* to be anonymous or have peculiar usernames, and in any case you don't know if the user's real name is in fact Diane Smith.

Comment: @crash: One doesn’t have to be all that Terence Tao-ish: at $10$ I’d have *loved* this site. Yes, most of it would have been over my head, but by no means all of it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I agree with that--I would have loved this site even 6 months ago! I recently discovered this gem myself. I simply meant that the *nature* of this site does not seem very appropriate for a 10-year old (which is probably why the age minimum was implement I would imagine), for people expect questions to be typeset correctly, to have shown effort, to be tagged correctly, etc. (all tasks more befitting of an older person IMO, albeit certainly *doable* by someone even younger than 10). I think I'll stop my comments and simply say: MSE is wonderful. On that we can all agree hopefully.

Comment: @crash The age minimum of 13 years that you mention on this site, as with other sites on the Internet, is precisely due to the COPPA (https://www.ftc.gov/enforcement/rules/rulemaking-regulatory-reform-proceedings/childrens-online-privacy-protection-rule).

Comment: @dragon Thanks for the link. Didn't know that. I think the point about the whole 10-year old thing should be changed to an $\epsilon$-year old...just for kicks. :)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Because of COPPA, apparently even "screen names" constitute [PII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information) and cause problems.

Comment: You guys are seriously underestimating the capabilities of today's youth. You're old. :P I am 26 (also old, compared to the youth of which I speak), and part of the first  generation to grow up with the internet as we know it. For a 10 year old to figure out how to join MSE or use LaTeX is not some amazing feat of a prodigy. It is normal. Think of how you learned to use [insert age-relevant technology here] when you were younger, and think of how much more difficult it was for all of the older people to do it.

Comment: I have friends who started using MSE when they were around 13 - 14. I myself used Physics forums at that age and began to browse MSE answers at ~15 (finally making an account at the turn of 16-17) . I think there's a lot of scope for younger people to use this site and we shouldn't assume so quickly that this is unusual. I can only imagine that the next generation after me will be even younger when they begin to use such resources

Comment: (I haven't had a chance to read or respond to comments in response to me in a while.) @MathNoob That is a great point in my opinion, thanks for your input. I see that you alluded to that idea earlier, Brian, so I should give you credit too.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think your answer is fine - setting up the subtraction could certainly be sufficient to help someone with this problem, especially since it should be fairly clear to them where those numbers are coming from. It's clearly a serious answer. However, AvZ does raise a valid objection - but I'd read that more as a stylistic thing (best resolved by AvZ writing their own answer) than a "This answer is bad" sort of thing. Your answer is valid, though it's very short in a way some people might not like.

That said, though, I suspect that, in reality, your answer does not specifically address what confused the OP; per their comment:

> I got stuck in the zero's and just got anxious and over thought the problem...

it seems that their trouble is in particular figuring out the second number. Your answer doesn't focus on this because their *question* doesn't - it was doomed from the start! A question like:

> How much more money is needed to get to 1.2 million if you have one million fifty thousand dollars? I can see that if you need 3 dollars and have 2 dollars then you need 3-2=1 dollar, but I'm having trouble writing out the numbers in my problem.

would be a good question. Their question was not and was rightly closed.

I do, however, feel that all the comments below the post are non-constructive - "What have you tried?" is a pretty lazy way to ask someone for context when it seems fairly clear that they're not going to have an answer to that. A comment like "If you wanted 10 dollars and had 7, how would you figure out how much more you needed?" would be quite helpful (to discern if the problem is in setting things up, or not knowing the general method - or what) - and I'm sure other users could think of many other constructive comments to leave on such a post.

Arithmetic is perfectly on topic here, subject to the same requirements other questions are. This site's customs for addressing questions lacking context is often more harsh than helpful, especially towards elementary questions. It is not necessarily "wrong" to answer a question like this one, but it's probably not effort well-spent unless you can read the OP's mind.

Comment: Thank you, @Meelo, for your comforting response. I guess all of us should think twice before answering questions like this, especially if they lack constructiveness. Furthermore, perhaps we on MSE answer so many high-level math questions that an arithmetic question is seen as anomaly. Hence, the snarky comments that the question had received. I did not understand why the user was accused of trolling, but Mike Miller's comment did somewhat convince me otherwise.

Comment: @dragon: There is a reasonable possibility that the OP was trolling, but it’s by no means certain, and some of the comments were distinctly off-putting. And while your answer does not *directly* address getting stuck in the zeroes (which does sound rather like a ten-year-old) — not surprising, since that problem wasn’t mentioned — it does completely straighten them out for her. Assuming that the question was genuine, you your answer probably helped; I consider it perfectly acceptable.

Comment: *"What have you tried?" is a pretty lazy way to ask someone for context when it seems fairly clear that they're not going to have an answer to that.* - Thank you. There's a certain point at which demanding effort is tantamount to refusing entry to people without a minimum level of math ability.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The user has been deleted. Would that be enough to conclude that the user was, in fact, trolling us?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code: Obviously not. The user might in fact have been exactly as represented and hence underage.

Comment: I'm with @BrianM.Scott on this one, dragon, you made a reasonable call in a not-completely-clear situation (WRT trolling vs sincerity). You should feel confident that similarly styled-to-the-question responses are equally appropriate.